# How to print command line arguments to a file

Tags: python, command-line

I am accepting 4 arguments from command line and want to use that to create a file in python.

My syntax is :

```
def configuredhcp(self,**kwargs):
                ''' Get the input parameters '''

                 client_ip = kwargs.get('client_ip',None)
                 client_mask = kwargs.get('client_mask',None)
                 option_routers = kwargs.get('option_routers',None)
                 option_broadcast = kwargs.get('option_broadcast',None)
                 range_ip = kwargs.get('range_ip',None)

                 infile = open('dhcpconf.txt', 'r+')
                 infile.write("Subnet  %s netmask %s " % (client_ip ,client_mask)
                 infile.write("option routers %s " % (option_routers)
                 infile.write("option broadcast-address %s; " % (option_broadcast)
                 infile.write(" range %s;" % (range_ip)
                 infile.close()
```

I get syntax error in line

> infile.write("option routers %s " % (option_routers)

Comment: If this is the exact code, you don't have matching closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `')'` closing braces in each write. Try this:-

```
def configuredhcp(self, **kwargs):
    ''' Get the input parameters '''

    client_ip = kwargs.get('client_ip', None)
    client_mask = kwargs.get('client_mask', None)
    option_routers = kwargs.get('option_routers', None)
    option_broadcast = kwargs.get('option_broadcast', None)
    range_ip = kwargs.get('range_ip', None)

    infile = open('dhcpconf.txt', 'r+')
    infile.write("Subnet  %s netmask %s " % (client_ip, client_mask))
    infile.write("option routers %s " % (option_routers))
    infile.write("option broadcast-address %s; " % (option_broadcast))
    infile.write(" range %s;" % (range_ip))
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked